# Is EM interpreted in a principal or vector bundle?

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, field-theory

I've read in a few places that EM is a $U(1)$-principal bundle; but is this correct? Isn't it rather an associated vector bundle using the adjoint representation of $U(1)$?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "EM". The gauge potential lives on a principal bundle, but all matter lives in associated bundles and one *could* think of the field strength as also living in an adjoint associated bundle (but it is really the curvature on the principal bundle, geometrically). So, what do you mean by "EM"?

Comment: @acuriousmind: I mean Maxwells equations; from what you say, if I've understood you correctly, the equations in a vacuum are expressed by a principle bundle; but when they have source, then one needs to use an associated bundle; what matter content is expressed then by the associated bundle in the adjoint rep'n?

Comment: The 4-potential of EM corresponds to the connection of the principal bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be our spacetime. Then, a gauge theory is given by a connection form $A$ on a principal bundle over it (that locally projects onto the spacetime in a way compatible with gauge transformations), which is the gauge potential.

Maxwell's equations<sup>1</sup> (in vacuum) are the equations of motion for the gauge field for the Yang-Mills action coupled to matter
$$ S[A] = \int_\mathcal{M} \operatorname{tr}(F\wedge\star F) + \rho(A)(\star J)$$
for some free current $J$, where $\rho$ is the representation $\star J$ transforms in. ($F = \mathrm{d}A$ is the field strength or curvature.)

For $\mathrm{U}(1)$, $\rho$ will never be the adjoint representation, since the adjoint representation is trivial for Abelian groups, and thus the term would simply vanish.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The second one, i.e. $\mathrm{d}\star F = \star J$. The first one, i.e. $\mathrm{d}F = 0$ is not an equation of motion, but follows directly from $\mathrm{d}^2 = 0$.</sup>